# MySQL C API libraries for iPhone

Tags: mysql, iphone, arm

Does anybody know where to get a MySQL libraries compiled for the arm iPhone architecture?

Or how to cross-compile MySQL for arm?

Thanx

Comment: Is it important that you use MySQL and not SQLLite? SQLLite databases can easily be embedded in iPhone apps using Apple's CoreData APIs. Using MySQL might be possible, but it would be much more of a hassle...

Comment: Accessing the database directly from an iPhone application doesn't sound like a good solution.

The sanest solution would probably be to create a web service and use consume the data from the web service in the iPhone application.

Comment: This is a good question, despite how crazy it sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1) Download the source code version of Connector/C from MySQL

2) Download cmake (if you have macports installed, type "sudo port install cmake")

3) Get toolchain files from http://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/coding/resources/how-to-guides/cross-compile-for-the-iphone/how-to-cross-compile-for-the-iphone-using-cmake

4) In the toolchain file for the simulator, remove one architecture from the line containing CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES

5) If you want to build for the simulator, copy the missing headers in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.2.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ (ip.h and in_system.h) from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk/usr/include/netinet

6) Create a directory called "compiled_library" somewhere, eg on your Desktop

7) Call cmake like this:
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/iphone-toolchain-file -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/compiled_library -DHAVE_FDATASYNC:INTERNAL=0

8) Note that if you want to run cmake a 2nd time, you might have to delete the cache file first

9) type make install

10) Now you have the compiled library in /path/to/compiled_library. Copy the header file directory and libmysql.a to your xcode project via "Add existing files...". The library should be automtically added to the linker stage.

11) WOOHOO. Use the mysql C API.

12) If this is too much work, I'm currently writing a MySQL wrapper framework for the iPhone. I will publish it sometime in the next ten years and put a link here.

EDIT:
Someone else created an Objective C Wrapper for the MySQL client library: http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/

Answer (score 1):

do you need client or server libraries? Anyway, since OS X supports unix scripts you should at least try build using "regular Unix" approach:

client:
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-c-building.html

server:
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing-source.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kumulos 'Hookup' http://www.kumulos.com/2011/07/06/introducing-hookup/ feature to build a suite of web services for your MySQL database.

Basically you define your different web services in the online control panel, then it builds all the Objective-C code and server side code.

I believe this is the easiest way to achieve your goals, and probably a lot better than using a direct Objective-C MySQL library.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

https://github.com/thrivesmart/just-mysql-example-mac-app-objective-c-xcode/issues/1

No compilation needed

Just use that LIB and replace the lib with the other repo!

Answer (score -4):

I don't believe you can run MySQL on the iPhone.  As Ben pointed out SQLite is built into the iPhone and you can use Core Data to manage structured data.

Comment: I don't need to run MySQL on the iPhone. I just need the MySQL client libraries for the ARM architechture