# iPhone connect to MySQL database on local network computer

Tags: iphone, mysql, localhost

I'm a bit of a noob to iPhone programming and I've read up on using PHP as the connection between an iPhone app and a remotely hosted MySQL database, but what I need to do is to connect directly to a MySQL database running on a local machine in my office. The machine is behind the same gateway and has an ip address similar to 192.169.x.x. Is that possible without PHP in the middle or anything else for that matter?  Thanks in advance. Really appreciate this site.

Comment: why do you want to do that instead of using some webservice?

Comment: The program I'm working on will include a distributable instance of MySQL in it that will install on the local network and the iPhone program will need to connect directly with it. I want to be able to bypass PHP as it would mean one less thing to support down the road.  I just d/l a program called DBTracklayer that allows me to connect using their app, so I know it's possible, but I need to be able to provide this functionality in my on app.  This wouldn't give the end user the ability to connect to any database, just one in the local network with an ip address similar to 192.168.x.x.

Comment: It must be possible because there are plenty of 3rd party apps that allow you to connect to your own MySQL instance.  MySQL has a C API which in theory you should be able to compile on iOS.  Here's a similar question with a more thorough answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/961742/mysql-c-api-libraries-for-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/ - that's an Objective-C library for accessing MySQL.

The conventional approach is to have your iPhone app POST or GET pages on a web interface that you separately program to access your data, but if you have your own reasons to bypass that, this approach should work.

An alternative would be for you to code the socket communications yourself (3306 to MySQL) - in effect, developing your own library of interface routines to MySQL. In either case, you have to be aware that you're exposing your MySQL interface to some serious vulnerabilities by putting it on the open Internet instead of mediating access through your own PHP code. YMMV.