# How to I connect an iPad directly to a MySQL Server?

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL C API libraries for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961742/mysql-c-api-libraries-for-iphone)

I am making an iPad application that needs send and get information from a MySQL database.  My boss refuses to use php on this project. I've looked everywhere and I cannot find a way to directly query and connect to a MySQL Database through an iOS application. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

-Freddy

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the MySQL client library for iOS, and link it into your project.  These posts look helpful:

[Build MySql client library for iPhone/iPad](http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=20)
[Use the MySQL client library in iOS project](http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=30)